# Android - Searching a fragment

Tags: android, search

Having some trouble searching an already created fragment instance. The problem is that I can only extend fragment, not listfragment etc.

I've tried onQueryTextListener and other methods, but I'm just lost right now.
I created a simple arraylist that's displayed. All I want to do is be able to search through the arraylist and display items based on text. I already have the xml file, it's just a simple one with a search view.

Here's the code:

```
public class SearchListFragment extends Fragment {

View games;
public SearchView search;
public ListView searchResults;

public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "Search list";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    ListView phoneListView = ((ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.games));

    ArrayList<String> gameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    gameList.add("Bloodborne: The Old Hunters");
    gameList.add("Kingdom Hearts III");
    gameList.add("Final Fantasy XV");

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, gameList);
    // Set The Adapter
    phoneListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    return rootView;

  }
}
```

Should I not extend fragment and extend listfragment and just try something new? I'm completely lost. The end result should just be a searchview, or even an on click search button, that prompts the user to type or click text, then refreshes the fragment page based on what they typed.

Sorry if the code contains irrelevant information, been messing around with a bunch of views and onclick methods.

I tried adding:

```
search = (SearchView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Searcher);
    search.setQueryHint("Start typing to search");

    searchResults = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.games);


    search.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFound) {

        }
    });

    search.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (newText.length() > 2) {
                    //todo, would display if text is more than 2 letters
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Which successfully brings up the text search (not the issue), but how do I refresh the fragment based on a search done on the arraylist?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you can extend ArrayAdapter and implement  filtering by overriding getFilter() method

Comment: But I have to extend Fragment because it's a seperate fragment page... I'm not able to extend two things, am I?

Comment: Are you trying to create a filter over list view data when user type some thing over search ? if yes then you need to do what @Roman Zhukov said, if you want I can give more hint on this.

Comment: Yes, but I thought you were only able to extend one thing per class? I currently am extending Fragment, how can I also extend ArrayAdapter for my SearchListFragment class? All I want to do is filter the Fragment based on a search. For the example if I type in "King" I want the fragment page to only display "Kingdom Hearts III" instead of all 3 items in the array gameList.

Comment: @Pulkit make your own custom array adapter then inside that array adapter create your filter accordingly, use that adapter in list view. when you do some query, filter out the data and call notifydataset change

Comment: ok thanks, will try it @dex

Comment: @Pulkit if you want, I can share starting approach with code ?

Comment: @dex that would be nice, pretty new to android. I have my adapter and Search class made. Just needa get them to work now.

Answer (score 0):

So create your custom array adapter some thing like this

This is your custom adapter class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{ 
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resID, List<String> items) 
    {
        mContext = context;
        mList = items;
        mResourceID = resID;
        mFilterList = new ArrayList<>();
        mFilterList.addAll(mList);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return mList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return mList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) 
    {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ListViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            convertView = View.inflate(mContext, mResourceID, null);
            holder = new ListViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CarTitle);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else
        {
            holder = (ListViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.name.setText(mList.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText)
    {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        mList.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) 
        {
            mList.addAll(mFilterList);
        } 
        else
        {
            for (String entry : mFilterList) 
            {
                if (entry.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) 
                {
                    mList.add(entry);
                }
                else if (entry.getCarBrand().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText))
                {
                    mList.add(entry);
                }
                else if (entry.getCarType().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText))
                {
                    mList.add(entry);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private static class ListViewHolder 
    {
        TextView name;
    }
    //members variable

    private final List<String> mList;
    private ArrayList<String> mFilterList;
    private int mResourceID;
    private final Context mContext;
}

This is your main class, make these changes

public class SearchListFragment extends Fragment 
{

View games;
public SearchView search;
public ListView searchResults;
public CustomAdapter mCustomAdapter;

public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "Search list";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    ListView phoneListView = ((ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.games));

    ArrayList<String> gameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    gameList.add("Bloodborne: The Old Hunters");
    gameList.add("Kingdom Hearts III");
    gameList.add("Final Fantasy XV");

    mCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, gameList);
    // Set The Adapter
    phoneListView.setAdapter(mCustomAdapter);
    return rootView;

  }
}
```

Now in your search query method do some thing like this

```
search = (SearchView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Searcher);
search.setQueryHint("Start typing to search");

searchResults = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.games);

search.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

@Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFound) {

        }
    });

    search.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (newText.length() > 2) {
                    //todo, would display if text is more than 2 letters
                    mCustomAdapter.filter(newText);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Hopefully this will give some hint to you how to implement filter and do search

Comment: Thanks @dex, but I figured it out early on. Will try to look at your code anyways!